# Apple ID p8 key manipulation

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, openssl, apple-id, p8

Used lib: https://github.com/patrickbussmann/oauth2-apple

Used class: \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Apple

Development of Authentification via AppleID in mobile app (ios) Backend: 1c-bitrix (not that important).

Used .p8 file from apple dev panel.

Responses from appleid server:

I get random errors with same request:
[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]
[image: error 3]

I already tried in .p8 file change UTF-8 to ANSI, change line breaks to "Windows style" - it did not help. What`s wrong?